# Should we always ignore the alg parameter in the JWT header?

Tags: security, rsa, jwt

In [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/) the author describes a scenario where hackers construct valid JWT tokens by exploiting the fact that in order to verify the signature the verifier first has to look at the header.  If we always use RSA with public private key pairs, does that completely avoid the possibility of this hack happening?

Here's a quote:

> Unfortunately, an attacker can abuse this. If a server is expecting a token signed with RSA, but actually receives a token signed with HMAC, it will think the public key is actually an HMAC secret key.

I assume this statement means that the code checking the token switches over to HMAC in the event that the `alg` key in the header says that the the token is using HMAC.  So if if we always use RSA and never HMAC and therefore never check the header, we just verify the token using our public key and if the verification fails we deny access, does that solve this?

Could this approach introduce any other security issues?

Comment: As the paper says, as long as you don't choose the algorithm based on what's in the header then you should be safe.

Comment: Great - I updated the subject to reflect the topic more accurately.

Comment: According to the paper, there is a vulnerability related to some libraries in some weakly typed languages (php,js). Verify a JWT with a public key as if it were an HMAC I consider it more a concrete bug than a wide vulnerability. I do not think that header verification should be omitted completely because there is useful information, such as the hashing algorithm that can be safely inferred (eg RS256 vs RS512)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes so as long as you know what Algo to expect and you are using the latest updated libraries you should be good. If you can visit the site  https://jwt.io , you will find that they too highlight this vulnerability and for the impacted libs they have mentioned the minimum version to use , which has the fix for the issue i.e. the Algo verification is not getting by-passed .

```
    verify(string token, string algorithm, string verificationKey)
```

This is what i understand .